# Rails: controller#show logic for a link_to root_path or :back

Tags: ruby-on-rails, back, link-to, referrer

How do I set up a Controller#show layouts "OK" button so that it will `link_to root_path` if the user is coming through the `new` > `create` actions

*but*

if user is viewing a list of already existing resources (effectively an index), then clicks on one to see the Controller#show (details), then the "OK" button will now take them back to the previous page (index)?

I'm using `store_location` and `redirect_back_or(default)` helper methods to handle `login_required` for certain controllers (including this controller). Can this be adopted to also work with my issue above? Or is there a better way?

In a nutshell, I think the button wants to `link_to "OK", :back` unless the previous action was the create (or sign_in) action.

I don't think we need to involve the `session` because the link doesn't need to persist. It's just one thing if it's coming from an index and another if it's coming from create or (sign_in)...just not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 4):

So, in `new` > `create` actions the user is redirected to `Controller#Show`. You can just pass a parameter along with it. For Eg you can modify your `redirect_to` to something like the following:

```
<%= redirect_to show_path(:param1 => "true") %>
```

Then in your `#Show` page, you can check

```
<% if !params[:param1].nil? and params[:param1] == true %>
     <%= link_to "OK", root_path %>
<% else %>
     <%= link_to "OK", :back %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This works…thanks! *will leave question open for a few days to see if there are other ways to handle this...*